# Docker (Linux) Error: no space left on device even if I have enough space

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have built docker image and while that I got the **Error: no space left on device**. This comes in the step where docker copies the oracle databse files. In my docker file it is this step:

```
ADD resources/oracle/database /data/home/oracle/database/
RUN chown -R oracle:oracle /data/home/oracle/database
```

This step takes some time when I build the image after that it prints this error:

```
Step 10/32 : ADD resources/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29.tar.gz /opt/tomcat
 ---> 092e001b744e
Step 11/32 : ADD resources/oracle/database /data/home/oracle/database/
 ---> 69218d6278b0
Step 12/32 : RUN chown -R oracle:oracle /data/home/oracle/database
 ---> Running in 4ae797185eeb
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /data/home/oracle/database/javavm/jdk/jdk8/admin/classes.bin: no space left on device
```

Hmm it seems for me that I dont have enough space on linux server. I then tried to check my space in linux as I am sure that I have much space. I run df -h and it looks like this:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         59G     0   59G   0% /dev
tmpfs            59G     0   59G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            59G  418M   59G   1% /run
tmpfs            59G     0   59G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        39G   30G  9.0G  77% /
/dev/sda1       200M  8.6M  192M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc       1008G  176G  781G  19% /data
/dev/sdd       1008G  466G  492G  49% /oracle
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /run/user/2003
```

Before I built the image it looked like this:

```
davinci@sii-dev-ora19:/opt/davinci]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         59G     0   59G   0% /dev
tmpfs            59G     0   59G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            59G  418M   59G   1% /run
tmpfs            59G     0   59G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        39G   16G   23G  42% /
/dev/sda1       200M  8.6M  192M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc       1008G  176G  781G  19% /data
/dev/sdd       1008G  466G  492G  49% /oracle
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /run/user/2003
```

Means That I had on /dev/sda3 23GB available before I built the image and only 9GB available after building the image.

**Question1:** why does it stop even when I still have 9GB avilable on that partition?
**Question2:** It seems that docker doesnt take space from the other partitions. On dev/sdc for example I have 718GB available. How to tell docker to take space from there?
**Question3:** It seems that docker write files into this folder /data/home/oracle/database/...
But I go to that folder with winscp I can find only the directory /data. Is the folder /data/home/oracle/database/ in container somehow or its really in linux file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question1: why does it stop even when I still have 9GB avilable on that partition?

You didn't when the error occurred. The error resulted in docker deleting the partial filesystem layer it had created. Note with overlay filesystems, a recursive chmod will copy every file in that directory tree, doubling the used disk space.

Note that you should also be watching for inode exhaustion when you get this write (`df -i`).

> Question2: It seems that docker doesnt take space from the other partitions. On dev/sdc for example I have 718GB available. How to tell docker to take space from there?

Docker stores data in `/var/lib/docker`. I'd recommend making that it's own partition, or relocating it using a symlink rather than trying to change the location docker looks. There are lots of tools out there that assume this directory name.

> Question3: It seems that docker write files into this folder /data/home/oracle/database/... But I go to that folder with winscp I can find only the directory /data. Is the folder /data/home/oracle/database/ in container somehow or its really in linux file system?

Docker uses namespaces, and one of those namespaces in the filesystem. The root directory in a docker container is not the root directory on the host, otherwise you'd have no isolation. This is typically implemented as an overlay filesystem under the docker directory, and each step of the Dockerfile may create a new filesystem layer used by overlay.